# Can a Helm pre-upgrade hook modify the pod-deletion-cost prior to doing a rolling update?

Tags: kubernetes, akka, kubernetes-helm

I need to the pods (e.g. scaled to 3 replicas) of a k8s deployment in a specific order to ensure that the oldest member (my cluster leader in an Akka / [Apache Pekko](https://pekko.staged.apache.org/docs/pekko/current/typed/cluster-membership.html#leader) cluster) is the last pod to be downed.

I want to use `controller.kubernetes.io/pod-deletion-cost` annotation for that in order to give the oldest member the highest [Pod deletion cost](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/#pod-deletion-cost).

My deployment is Helm based, so now I am wondering if I can use a Helm `pre-upgrade` [Hook](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/) in order to:

- in `pre-upgrade` hook phase:

  - query the Apache Pekko cluster management API in order to find out the oldest member (cluster leader)
  - calculates the `pod-deletion-cost`
  - applies the `pod-calculation-cost` for the pods of my deployment
- performs the upgrade using `RollingUpdate` `updateStrategy`

  - adhering to the defined `controller.kubernetes.io/pod-deletion-cost` and updating the cluster leader last

I am wondering if this would even be possible - I am not an expert on Helm hooks and Kubernetes annotations and maybe have wrong assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

maybe I could help you.
The core of this issue is how to perform operations accessing the api-server during the pre-upgrade hook phase. A common and standard approach is to create a job during the [pre-upgrade](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/) phase to execute the desired operations. Below, I will explain in detail how to create this job:

1. you should place the YAML file related to the job in the templates directory and specify the annotations as "helm.sh/hook": pre-upgrade.
2. Typically, we also need YAML files related to [rbac](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) because we need to grant the job permission to access the corresponding API.
3. We also need to control the creation order of each file, which can be achieved using the "helm.sh/hook-weight"
4. Do not forget patch "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy" annotation

You can see this: https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/vmware-tanzu/velero?modal=template&template=cleanup-crds.yaml, it cleans up crds when pre-delete. Actually, all files you need may be like:

1. templates/hooks/clusterrole.yaml

> ```
> apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
> kind: ClusterRole
> metadata:
>   name: xxx
>   annotations:
>     "helm.sh/hook": pre-upgrade
>     "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-5"
>     "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
>   labels:
>     ...
> rules:
> - apiGroups: 
>     - xxx
>   resources: 
>     - xxx
>   verbs: 
>     - create
>     - patch
>     - update
>     - get
>     - list
> ```

2. templates/hooks/clusterrolebinding.yaml

> ```
> apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
> kind: ClusterRoleBinding
> metadata:
>   name: xxx
>   labels:
>     ...
>   annotations:
>     "helm.sh/hook": pre-upgrade
>     "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-3"
>     "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
> subjects:
>   - kind: ServiceAccount
>     namespace: xxx
>     name: xxx
> roleRef:
>   kind: ClusterRole
>   name: xxx
>   apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
> ```

3. templates/hooks/serviceaccount.yaml

> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: ServiceAccount
> metadata:
>   name: xxx
>   namespace: xxx
>   annotations:
>     "helm.sh/hook": pre-upgrade
>     "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-4"
>     "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
>   labels:
>     ...
> ```

4. templates/hooks/pre-updrade.yaml

Files 1~3 are used to ensure pre-upgrade.yaml have enough power to access api-server. Pre-upgrade.yaml describe what you want to do in pre-upgrade. You may need to build a base_image whith kubelet for it.
pre-upgrade.yaml may like this:

> ```
>     spec:
>       serviceAccountName: xxx
>       containers:
>         - name: kubectl
>           image: your_kubectl_container_image
>           imagePullPolicy: Always
>           command:
>             - /bin/sh
>           args:
>             - -c
>             - |
>               set -e
>               kubectl get xxx
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot @HrimfaxiYKW - this looks already very useful. I will try it that way and mark as accepted answer if it works :)

Comment: If any problems, plz contact me. Hope I can help u :)